# Отрезок с минимумом не проходит тесты

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-3.6

В этой задаче вы можете использовать одномерные массивы (или их аналоги), циклы и операторы ветвления. Запрещается использовать многомерные массивы, вложенные циклы и функции стандартной библиотеки работы с контейнерами.

Задана последовательность (массив) целых чисел длины n своими элементами a0,a1,…,an−1, а также целое число m. Найдите длину наибольшего отрезка массива, такого что минимальное число в этом отрезке равно m. Все числа в массиве различны, и гарантируется, что в массиве встречается число m.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных заданы два целых числа n и m (1≤n≤20000, −10^9≤m≤10^9) — размер массива и некоторый элемент массива. Во второй строке заданы через пробел n целых чисел a0,a1,…,an−1 (−10^9≤a^i≤10^9) — элементы массива.

Выходные данные
Выведите одно целое положительное число — длину искомого отрезка.

Примеры

входные данные
1 -1
-1
выходные данные
1

входные данные
3 2
3 1 2
выходные данные
1

входные данные
4 -5
10 -1 -5 20
выходные данные
4

```
n, m = [int (x) for x in input().split()]
a=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
mini = a[0]
v=0
for i in range (-1, 1, n+1):
    if a[i]<mini:
        mini=a[i]
    if mini>m:
        mini, m = m, mini
    v=abs(abs(m)-abs(mini))
print(abs(v-1))
```

Не проходит на 4 тесте. Учитель сказала, что-то про то, что m вроде и не может быть в массиве, и может быть, и я не понимаю как это решить. Кто-нибудь, напишите код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно например вот так :)

```
n, m = map(int,input().split())
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
ind = []
for i in range (0, n):
    if a[i] == m:ind.append(i)
if len(ind) == 0:
    #если в массиве нет такого элемента,
    #значит и нету такого подмассива с этим минимумом
    print(0)
else:
    max_leng = 0
    for j in ind:
        leng = 0
        #проверяем на наличия очередного минимума справа от позиции m
        for i in range(j, n):
            if a[i] < m:break
            else:leng+=1
        #аналогично слева
        for i in range(j - 1, -1, -1):
            if a[i] < m:break
            else:leng += 1
        max_leng = max(max_leng, leng)
    print(max_leng)
```

Comment: В условии же четко написано, что такое число всегда есть. Зачем эта бессмысленная проверка?

Comment: Ну все же в промышленной разробки это надо учитовать, я не дочитал условие, автор может и сам эту проверку забрать если нужно)

Comment: Сработает для m=2 и списка [1,3,2,3,0,4,2,5,5,5,5]?

Comment: Вы правы, я не пересмотрел вариант когда етих значений много много

Comment: В условии указано, что все элементы массива различны.

Comment: Эта программа все тесты прошла, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
def mmin(a, m):
    l = len(a)
    maxlen = 0
    state = 0
    start = -1
    for i in range(l + 1):
        if i == l or a[i] < m:
            if state > 1:
                maxlen = max(i - start, maxlen)
            state = 0
        else:
            if state == 0:
                start = i
                state = 1
            if a[i] == m:
                state += 1
    return maxlen
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция поиска может быть такой:

```
def longest(n, m, a):
    mq = cq = f = 0
    for e in a:
        if e >= m:
            cq += 1
            f = f or e == m
            if f and cq > mq:
                mq = cq
        else:
            cq = f = 0
    return mq
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/QGFBB91829).

Comment: Не фурычит на  `11 2   // 1 3 2 3 0 4 3 5 5 5 5`

Comment: Недостатки свои знаю, пути исправления кода вижу :)

Answer (score 0):

Идея решения.

1. Если m=min(lst), то ответ длина списка.
2. Если не так, то список разделяется на 2 части относительно минимума. Выбираем ту часть, где m и идем на п.1

   ```
   def getLen(m, lst):
       im=lst.index(m)
       imin=lst.index(min(lst))
       if imin==im:
          return(len(lst))
       if imin<im:
          return getLen(m, lst[imin+1:])
       if imin>im:
          return getLen(m, lst[:imin])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Заметим, что все числа различны. Значит нам достаточно расширить подотрезок с элементом M влево и вправо до тех пор, пока все числа, которые в него входят > M. Итоговая асимптотика: O(N).

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = input().split()
idx = -1
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
    if a[i] == m:
        idx = i
i1 = idx - 1
while i1 > -1 and a[i1] > m:
    i1 -= 1
i2 = idx + 1
while i2 < n and a[i2] > m:
    i2 += 1
i2 -= 1
i1 += 1
print(i2 - i1 + 1)
```